# WebStorm Emmet creates <Single /> tag rather than opening and closing tabs

Tags: webstorm, emmet

I have just reinstalled WebStorm, previously when pressing tab in a JSX field opening and closing tags were created, but now only a single, self-enclosed tag is created.

The Emmet settings for JSX only show an on/off toggle. How can I fix this?

Previously:

tab + `Component` = `<Component></Component>`

Currently:

tab + `Component` = `<Component/>`

Comment: From an XML perspective - the above two tags are basically identical anyway. Does it really matter?

Comment: @shadow It's personal preference, but I don't like using the children prop since it defeats the purpose of JSX. Should at least be an option

Comment: I agree it should be an option - but can you please elaborate on how it "defaults the purpose of JSX"?

Comment: @shadow JSX is just a fancy way of representing objects in js, so without it we would just be writing plain objects, which I think are more succint. JSX gives a visual benefit with the nesting, without which I would prefer objects.

`<Component someProp={someValue} children={<OtherComponent children={<ThirdComponent />} /> />`

Is way more messy than object syntax IMO:

`component: { someProp: 'someVal', children: [ otherComponent: { children: [ thirdComponent ] } ] }`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was implemented in 2017.1.2 as per user requests: [WEB-25937](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-25937) and [WEB-24502](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24502).

You [cannot disable](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-24502#comment=27-2156716) this new behaviour in WebStorm 2017.1.2 or newer.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26468 -- watch this ticket (star/vote/comment) to get notified on any progress.

---

**UPDATE 2020-09-28:**

The aforementioned **WEB-26468** ticket [has been implemented](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-26468#focus=Comments-27-2337530.0-0) since 2017.2.2 version.

Current behaviour is:

```
View => <View></View>

View/ => <View/>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I am using Webstorm 2018.3.

I was using the first method, but then I found out you can do it the second way:

```
<Co + (Tab or Enter) = <Component/>
Component + Tab = <Component></Component>
```